# DataGrid Style template not applying to All DataGrids

Tags: wpf, datagrid, styles

I have a Style that I am trying to apply to a DataGrid, but it only works if i give it a key and explicitly say to use it.

```
<Application ...>
<Application.Resources>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}" x:Key="ErrorStyle">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" 
                        Foreground="Orange"
                        FontSize="12pt">
                        !!!!
                    </TextBlock>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="1">
                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
                    </Border>
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource ErrorStyle}" />
<Style TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource ErrorStyle}" />
<Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource ErrorStyle}" />
<Style TargetType="DataGrid" BasedOn="{StaticResource ErrorStyle}" />
</Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

The above works for all Textboxs, Labels, Buttons within my Application. But it isn't working for DataGrids.
So then I changed the DataGrids style to be:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGrid" BasedOn="{StaticResource ErrorStyle}" x:Key="DataGridErrorStyle" />
```

And then explicitly add it to my DataGrids like so

```
<DataGrid Name="myGrid" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=DataGridErrorStyle}" />
```

Then it all works fine.

I'm just wondering if anyone knows why a DataGrid wouldn't use the implicit Style defined? Why does it require explicit Styling?

Comment: I have tried your code and it seems to work fine on DataGrid with the implicit Style. I didn't need to add it explicitly as you did. Are you sure it's not working? If you still find it's not working, maybe you could indicate precisely how the error condition is being set on the DataGrid so I can reproduce it more exactly...

Comment: When i make the Data Grid's call implicit... it DOES display an error... but it is just a red border (I believe the default for an Error Template maybe?).. The Buttons/Lables/Textboxes all correctly get the green border & textblock defined in the Control Template....

I went ahead and removed the explicit call, and removed the Key from the style... and it went back to displaying just a red border for the datagrid... while all the others still get the green border & textblock...

is that what you get?

Comment: No I'm afraid I get the same effect, a green box with exclamation marks, whether I explicitly set an x:Key for the style or just rely on it coming implicitly. Is it possible that your DataGrid is inheriting a style from somewhere else in your code that is overriding the app default one?

Comment: wow... I had a partial Style in my Main Window.. and had it's type set to DataGrid.... *slaps head*

Post what you wrote as an Answer, I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: OK, posted. Glad you managed to get it sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried it, I got a green box with exclamation marks as required, whether I explicitly set an x:Key for the style or just rely on it coming implicitly. Is it possible that your DataGrid is inheriting a style from somewhere else in your code that is overriding the app default one?